# Where should ajax backend files be placed in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a CI project. I have a bunch of view files from which ajax calls are made to PHP backend files. I want to understand within the structure of codeigniter where I should place these backend files? I dont think I can put them as helpers. They are not really model files, nor are they controllers. Where is a good location to put such files which accept ajax requests and update backend db?

Comment: "They are not really model files, nor are they controllers." — Since you are using an MVC framework, perhaps you should refactor them into models, views and controllers?

Comment: Make folder `js` or `javascripts` at your root folder and include them.

Comment: As an ajax request needs to call something which takes in data, does some processing or information retrieval and then passes data for output, I'd argue that anything called via Ajax is a controller method

Comment: you have to show some of this files - because i think this is a concept problem rather than a "location" problem

Answer (score 0):

We use a separate set of controllers serving a RESTful API within our CodeIgniter project, returning results to jQuery AJAX requests.

eg:

```
/controllers
```

Normal application page controllers (HTML/PHP views)

```
/controllers/api
```

API controllers (JSON/XML views)

Both can share the same models obviously. Works well for us!